# Sort yii2 expand data in ascending order

Tags: php, sorting, yii2, dataprovider

I am working on the yii2 framework and I have an API from which I get "groups" from the table and it has a relationship with another table called "permissions" and this "permission" table has a foreign key for the "group" table "group_id" so for this the API is:
http://localhost/yii2/backend/web/index.php?r=configuration/permissiongroup&expand=permissions&sort=name
response:
[

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "group_a",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "id": "34",
            "name": "z",
            "group_id": 8
        },
        {
            "id": "35",
            "name": "x",
            "group_id": 8
        },
        {
            "id": "36",
            "name": "y",
            "group_id": 8
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "group_b",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "id": "22",
            "name": "b",
            "group_id": 3
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "name": "d",
            "group_id": 3
        },
        {
            "id": "24",
            "name": "a",
            "group_id": 3
        }
    ]
},
```

In this API I have managed to sort the "groups" object in ascending order by adding the "sort" parameter in the URL but I need to sort the "permissions" object in ascending order so how can I achieve that in the yii2 framework?

Comment: If you are using `dataprovider` then below answer will work else show the query as well

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to achieve this by the help of active query in the model of "permissionGroup" where I already had a function called "getPermissions" so I have just placed an orderBy and it worked.

```
public function getPermissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Permission::className(), ['group_id' => 'id'])->orderBy('name ASC');
}

public function extraFields() {
    return ['permissions'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo attribute for sorting and set the appropriate sorting parameters for that.

The URL could be: http://localhost/yii2/backend/web/index.php?r=configuration/permissiongroup&expand=permissions&sort=name2

Configure the sorting like that:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['name2'] = [
    'asc'  => [
        'groups.name' => SORT_ASC,
        'permissions.name' => SORT_ASC,
    ],
    'desc' => [
        'groups.name' => SORT_DESC,
        'permissions.name' => SORT_DESC,
    ],
];
```

Comment: thanks for the response but it does not work for me I don't know why but I have managed to achieve this with the help of an Active query in the model.